# UIDatePicker and the day selection

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

trying to use a uidatepicker. have a method that fires when the value of the datepicker changes. it passes the date value, but when i try and take that date, my days portion is acting goofy.  it returns the number of days since the beginning of the year, not the actual month day. so say February 3rd, instead of 3, i get 34.

```
-(IBAction)datePickerValueChanged: (id)sender;
{        
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD"];

    self.date = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[sender date]];
    NSLog(@"date: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[sender date]]);

    [dateFormatter release];
}
```

for april 12th, i get:

```
2011-10-27 14:22:41.939 Satshot[12789:40b] date02: 2011-04-102
```

i'm guessing my dateformatter is causing it, but i don't understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong format specifier. You need `"yyyy-MM-dd"`

http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Update, YYYY and DD are both wrong. Thanks @jrturton.

Comment: You spotted DD and missed YYYY, I spotted YYYY and missed DD!

Answer (score 3):

From the [Data Formatting Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1):

> It uses yyyy to specify the year component. A common mistake is to use
>   YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year
>   (of "Week of Year"), used in the ISO year-week calendar. In most
>   cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same number, however they may be
>   different. Typically you should use the calendar year.

In addition, `DD` should be `dd`.

Though why not just use the date to hold your value internally?

Also, note that creating a date formatter is an expensive exercise, valueChanged on a picker view could be called tens of times a second as the user scrolls through. If you must use a formatter, cache it.

Comment: so you'd suggest to make my formatter into an instant variable that gets set in viewDidLoad? Or have valueChanged just store the new date and when the users presses the "select" and have the formatter work there? basiclly just prevent the formatter from being alloc'ed/released every time the value changes?

Comment: Actually I'd suggest that `self.date` be an `NSDate` rather than an `NSString` and you only use a formatter on it when you actually need to do something with the value, **AND** that that formatter is an instance variable so you aren't creating and destroying it all the time.